# Sending Driverless Print Jobs (PDF)

Tags: printing

I have tried a number of code variants for C#/>net 6.0 code below. They all return code 200/Success but no job prints. The printer is listed as supporting IPP Everywhere https://www.pwg.org/ipp/everywhere.html. The IP gateway is enabled on the printer. I was also able to create and print to the same printer via a local IPP printer using the Windows generic PostScript driver.  Any ideas why my driverless code doesn't work?

The following code runs and submits the print request. It returns 200/Success/Ok but no job prints. Is there some standard recipe for the header that should work on any IPP supporting printer (OKI C844)?

```
    public async Task SubmitPrintJob(string filePath) {
    string paperTray = "tray-1";

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            // IPP header
            byte[] ippHeader = new byte[] {
                0x01, 0x01, // version number
                0x00, 0x02, // operation-id (Print-Job)
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, // request-id
                0x01, 0x47, 0x00, 0x11, // operation-attributes-tag + charset attributes
                0x75, 0x73, 0x2D, 0x61, 0x73, 0x63, 0x69, 0x69,
                0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x15,
                0x61, 0x74, 0x74, 0x72, 0x69, 0x62, 0x75, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x2D, 0x63, 0x68, 0x61, 0x72, 0x73, 0x65, 0x74,
                0x00, 0x05, 0x75, 0x74, 0x66, 0x2D, 0x38,
                0x44, 0x00, 0x12, // document-format tag + length of the following "application/pdf" string
                0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x2F, 0x70, 0x64, 0x66, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00
            };

            // Read PDF file bytes
            byte[] pdfBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath);

            // Concatenate IPP header and PDF bytes
            byte[] requestData = new byte[ippHeader.Length + pdfBytes.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(ippHeader, 0, requestData, 0, ippHeader.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(pdfBytes, 0, requestData, ippHeader.Length, pdfBytes.Length);

            // Create HttpContent
            var content = new ByteArrayContent(requestData);

            // Send POST request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(printerUri, content);

            // Check response
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Print job sent successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send print job: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You want to check what's in the *content* of the response you're getting back from the printer.  The success status code tells you that the printer accepted what you posted, but you can't assume it means that it processed it correctly.  There's probably more info in the HTTP response.

Comment: I didn't see any thing obvious in the response. Do you have any suggestions on content I should be looking for?

Comment: If you're not finding anything there, I'd suggest you look at page 38 or 42 here and make sure you're following the approach that validates the print job.  Apparently there are good and bad approaches to getting the job done. 
 https://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/candidates/cs-ippig20-20150821-5100.19.pdf